# Bash: How to remove all blank lines on all files with an extensions

Tags: bash, sed

I'd need to remove all empty lines which are contained in all the files named "pom.xml". I've come up with this:

```
find . -name 'pom.xml' -exec sed '/^$/d'  {} \;
```

But it just prints out the output on the screen, which is by the way correct. I'd need however to change the files with that command. Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Does your version of sed support the `-i` option? If not, use perl.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-i` flag to sed, which means instantly change the file in place, instead of output the result.

```sh
find . -name 'pom.xml' -exec sed -i '/^$/d'  {} \;
```